# What does this php code means? i understand the $key=>$val, but i m not getting is $pre

Tags: php, sql, database

What does this php code mean?

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $pre = ($i > 0) ? ', ' : '';
    $columns .= $pre.$key;
    $values .= $pre."'".$val."'";
    $i++;
}
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columns.") VALUES (".$values.")";
```

Comment: He is defining `$pre` by `ternary operator`... Look for it on google...

Comment: As per your code is concern, it is used for concatenating values with `,`

Comment: does this code has the functionality of anti sql injection ?

Answer (score 0):

It converts and array (key => value) into a insert SQL.

For example:

```
$array = array('date' => '2016-06-19 12:00:00', 'name' => 'Jamie');
```

Would be converted to:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (date, name) VALUES ('2016-06-19 12:00:00', 'Jamie');
```

Comment: but what is the $pre variable .. what it is used for  ?

Comment: and does this provides anti sql injection ?

Comment: it's a perfect example of a *very bad code*. See php manual for `implode`.

Comment: @jack_007 The `$pre` variable is used to determine whether it needs to prepend a comma to the start of the row, in this instance is states if it's the first time it's looping then don't add a comma, otherwise do add a comma. No it doesn't prevent SQL injection as the variables are not escaped, see [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Comment: @JamieBicknell if i'll use mysqli_real_escape_string then do i need to use prepare and bind parameters for fully anti sql injection or just real escape string will help me out for preventing sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

The Actual Code is this i think...

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $pre = ($i > 0) ? ', ' : '';
    $columns .= $pre.$key;
    $values .= $pre."'".$val."'";
    $i++;
}
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columns.") VALUES (".$values.")";
```

Here you can write..

```
$pre = ($i > 0) ? ', ' : '';//this method is known as ternary Operator...
```

Into this...

```
if($i > 0) //this is classic if else method...
{
  $pre = ', '; 
} 
else
{ 
   $pre ='';
}
```

Comment: @jack_007 `$key` is column name of db table... So  `$pre.$key` is `column_name1` when $pre is '' and `, column_name2` when $pre is ', '.... See another answer...

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer if it clears your doubt...But never ask these type of questions(don't understand what this code does type) here... ask your mentor first :)

Comment: explain me that two lines with each variable . what is the use of " and , . what it derives ?